# How do I loop through a dictionary to see its values?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to get the hang of objective-c and how to use dictionaries. I tried a small example, but it keeps crashing for me. Here is my dictionary and an attempt to loop the dictionary keys.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
                             @"anObject" : @"@hej",
                             @"helloString" : @"Hello, World!",
                             @"magicNumber" : @42,
                             @"aValue" : @33
                             };

for(NSString *key in dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"key:%@", key);
    NSLog(@"value:%@", [[dictionary valueForKey:key] string]);
}
```

It crashes with a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception >'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString string]: >unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1078590a8'

Here on the return line:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,     
        NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
```

Comment: According to your recent Qs: Are you aware of the possibility to print out a whole collection with `NSLog( "a collection: %@", dictOrArrayOrWhateverCollection )`. Usually you do not have to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

`NSLog()` will call the `[NSObject description]` method of any object you pass it, so this will work fine for you:

```
NSLog(@"value:%@", dictionary[key]);
```

There is no `string` method, so that's why you are getting the *unrecognized selector* exception.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! Could you just elaborate a bit on what you just did? Objective-C seems so... confusing to me

Comment: @WhipperSnapper I tested if the value was of type `NSNumber` and used the method it provides to provide a string representation.

Comment: Why do you need to call `stringValue` on `NSNumber` values? `NSLog(@"value:%@", value)` will log `NSNumber`s.

Comment: @Willeke You might be onto something; `NSLog()` will call the object's `description` method which will generate a string anyway...